# sort list by frequency of an Attribute of objects

Tags: python, sorting, object

I have a list of people. Every element of the list is an object of a class Person and has 3 attributes: name, age, height.
I need to sort this list by frequency of a name in list and if frequency is the same in alphabetical order using only sorted, no loops.
Example (objects):

```
[<name=Ellie, age=20, height=1.74>,
 <name=Sebastian, age=15, height=1.7>,
 <name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.82>,
 <name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.81>,
 <name=Alex, age=19, height=1.8>
]
 -> 
[<name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.82>,
 <name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.81>,
 <name=Alex, age=19, height=1.8>,
 <name=Ellie, age=20, height=1.74>,
 <name=Sebastian, age=15, height=1.7>
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the list contains objects whose name is asserted in the object property called `name` this will work:

```
lst.sort(key= lambda x: (lst.count(x), x.name))
```

Comment: @SyedMAbbasHaiderTaqvi Mistake. Try and see for yourself.

Comment: This will sort the list by the frequency of an object, not the name in it.

Comment: @alex wrong. This resolves both parameters `...x.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **counter & sort**

```
lst = ['ellie', 'sebastian', 'lukas', 'lukas', 'alex']
lst = sorted(lst)
from collections import Counter
result = [item for items, c in Counter(lst).most_common()
          for item in [items] * c]
# Output of result


['lukas', 'lukas', 'alex', 'ellie', 'sebastian']
```

Comment: But names are only an attribute of an object.
List itself is: 
[<name=Ellie, age=20, height=1.74>, <name=Sebastian, age=15, height=1.7>, <name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.82>, <name=Lukas, age=19, height=1.81>, <name=Alex, age=19, height=1.8>]
and i need to sort it by an attribute of an object

Answer (score 0):

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, name, age,height):
        self.name = name
        self.age=age
        self.height=height
p1=People("John",36,5.8)
p2=People("Mary",24,5.6)
p3 = People("John", 42, 6.1)
p4=People("Mel",18,5.9)
p5=People("John",26,5.7)
p6=People("Mary",32,5.11)
baselist=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6]

basename=[]
for obj in baselist:
    basename.append((obj.name,obj.height))
basename.sort()
finalobjlist=[]
for i in basename:

    for j in baselist:
        if i[0]==j.name and i[1]==j.height:
            finalobjlist.append(j)
print("")
for i in finalobjlist:
    print(i.name,i.age,i.height)
```

**NOTE: ASSUMING Everyone's height is unique**,
I've sorted the initial names, and then compared it to the original obj's height and name finally appended it to a new array.

**Output:**

```
John 26 5.7
John 36 5.8
John 42 6.1
Mary 32 5.11
Mary 24 5.6
Mel 18 5.9
```

The final ppl objects are stored in a list (finalobjlist).

Answer (score 0):

so I made the class as u mentioned like

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,age,height,name) -> None:
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
```

and a list of people like

```
a = [Person(1,1,"ellie"),Person(1,1,"sebastian"),Person(1,1,"lukas"),Person(1,1,"lukas"),Person(1,1,"alex")]
```

next I counted the frequency

```
counts = {}
for i in a:
    if i.name not in counts:
        counts[i.name]=0
    counts[i.name]+=1
counts
```

and using this key u can sort in your required manner
mind the negative count to give output in manner u requested

```
key = lambda element:(-counts[element.name],element.name)
k = sorted(a,key=key)
```

output will be like:

```
for i in k:
    print(i.name)
```

```
lukas
lukas
alex
ellie
sebastian
```